# C++ print vector and replace missing elements

Tags: c++, printf

I have a vector of random integers, sorted. The elements are one between 1 and 10, one between 11 and 20, one between 21 to 30 and so on, if a number is missing I want to print an *. Any ideas how to do it?

```
std::vector<int> v = { 3, 14, 35, 47, 71 }; //vector size is 5 and numbers can go up to 99
int i = 0;
for (int j = 1; j < 11; ++j)  
{
    if (i<5  &&  (v.at(i) < j*10))
    {
        std::cout << ' ' << v.at(i) ;
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "  *  " ;
    }

}
```

output should be:  3 14 * 35 47 * * 71

I'm thinking going through a loop checking if each element is part of  a specific set of numbers, like v[0]<11 print the element else print '*'

Later edit: got it

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please show the work you've already written so far, and explain how exactly your program doesn't work or doesn't produce the expected results. You have to show your work first, and it must be a good-faith real attempt to implement your task and not a few token lines of code, before asking for help on stackoverflow.com. We don't write entire programs for other people, here. For more information, see [ask] questions, take the [tour], and read the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed a bit your program, now it works so you wanted:

```
int main() {

    vector<int> v = { 3, 14, 35, 47, 71 }; //vector size is 5 and numbers can go up to 99
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 10 ; j <= 100 && i < 5; j += 10)
    {
        if (j == 100)
            j--;

        if (v.at(i) <= j && v.at(i) >= (j - 10))
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << v.at(i);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "  *  ";
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```